# How to add Dynamic SubTitle Overlay on OutPut Video using GPUImage iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, editing, gpuimage

Currently I am working on Video Processing application. I record video using GPUImage for iOS. Video is generated Perfect but i also want to add dynamic subtitles in Video i.e text change with varying time. I don't have any idea how to do subtitles in exported video using GPUImage so i am having difficulty in getting required Output. Kindly help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: post question here https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues?state=open

Comment: Did you try anything.

Comment: Have you seen the FilterShowcase sample application? Scroll down to the UI Element example, which does just this, but on live video.

Comment: Given Below is link of video in which you will see multiple texts at multiple times. I want to achieve something like this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hco1ba6nltzgwj/IMG_0335.mov